# Making maven release to work with perforce repository

Tags: maven, perforce, release, maven-release-plugin, maven-scm

I am new to perforce and trying to get release process to work. Upon googling on this topic, I tried few suggestions, but nothing worked. Finally came across a post here on stackoverflow([Configuring Perforce scm into maven project to get latest changelist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9885490/configuring-perforce-scm-into-maven-project-to-get-latest-changelist)) and followed the link from the solutions, which is:

https://swarm.workshop.perforce.com/files/guest/dantran/p4maven/README.md#view

I can perform "mvn scm:status" and "mvn scm:changelog", but it fails to do the release. First it fails with the error saying "Access is denied" while modifying the pom.xml file, so I had to manually remove the read-only flag from this file. I would expect plugin to manage this.
Second problem is that it keeps failing with "Changelist not available" error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:prepare (default-cli) on project sandbox: An error is occurred in the tag process: Exception while executing SCM command. Unable to retrieve current change list number: Changelist not available -> [Help 1]
```

I am not sure what to do further as I have run out of different ideas.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to define the server on your settings.xml
for example:

```
<servers>
  <server>
    <id>rtc:9444</id>
    <username>build</username>
    <password>build</password>
  </server>
</servers>
```